# Ember Data hasMany foreach within controller

Tags: ember.js, controller, ember-data

I currently have the following models setup using Ember Data and the Local storage adaptor.

```
App.Game = DS.Model.extend
 stage: DS.attr('number')
 level: DS.attr('number')
 actions: DS.hasMany('App.Action')

App.Action = DS.Model.extend
 type: DS.attr('string')
 time: DS.attr('number')
 game: DS.belongsTo('App.Game')
```

I can access each action from within the template using

```
{{#each actions}}
 {{type}}
{{/each}}
```

But I would like to access this same data from within the controller.

Is there are any to do this?

The following returns the actions length but I'd like to forEach over each action.

```
actionsLength: (->
 @get('actions').get('length')
).property('actions.@each')
```

The route for this controller like the following.

```
App.GameRoute = Ember.Route.extend
 model: (params) ->
  App.Game.find(params.game_id)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending from which controller you want access to the actions, have you tried to access your controller's `content`, for example:

```
App.ActionsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  myFunction: function() {
    this.get('content').forEach(function(action) {
      console.log(action.get('type'));
    });
  }
});
```

Or from your `GamesController`:

```
App.GamesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  myFunction: function() {
    this.get('content').forEach(function(game) {
      game.get('actions').forEach(function(action) {
        console.log(action.get('type'));
      });
    });
  }
});
```

*(sorry for not coffescriptifying the code)*

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, I had tried the above but because you confirmed what I was doing was correct I tried a few other things. If I refresh the page each action.get('type') returns null. If I access the page via a linkTo or transition the type data is there.

Any ideas where it may not be loading on a refresh? 

Thanks for your help! Was driving me nuts and turned out I was doing it the right way but being caught out by another issue.

Comment: @TomCoates, could you update your question with how your route looks like from where your are loading the records? Also have you setup the `hasMany` relation to be `embedded: 'load'` which is the default or `embedded: 'always`?

Comment: If I use `@get('actions').get('firstObject')` I can access the first action even on page refresh. I will add how the route looks to my original question.

Comment: @TomCoates, this can happen since the records are loaded asyncronously the `HasManyArray` is filled as records arrive, you should be sure that all records are loaded before looping over them. Without seeing how your setup looks like it's a little bit tricky to guess

Comment: Still not sure why when I simple console.log action within the forEach I can see the type within data.attributes when refreshing the page. Seems like the data is there but simply cant access it using this.get('type'). I have tried both 'load' and 'always'. Thanks again for your assistance. I appreciate it is difficult without seeing the full setup.